# How to get data from database mongodb without models in django?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, nosql

my problem is that my database is too large and I don't want to create any models

since it's legacy one, and I will have to call different tables dynamically,

so I just want to pull data from it. Is that possible in Django?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you use Django ORM to perform your queries, you can use SQL, with connection cursor.

As you can see from the following code example:

```
from django.db import connection

def custom_sql(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM legacy_table where id=1") # or another SQL
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row
```

But, if you want use Django ORM, you need create a model with Meta option `managed=False`, like the following example:

```
class LegacyTableModel(models.Model):
    # fields

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

With `managed=False`, no database table creation, modification, or deletion operations will be performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an existing table or a database view that has been created by some other means. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#managed)